# How to customize CKEditor Inline Editor for full Page support?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor, django-ckeditor

I have basic tutorial for CKEditor Samples » Replace Textarea with Inline Editor
But I can't get full page.

```
<script>   
    var cfg1 = { toolbar: 'Full', fullPage:true, allowedContent:true, extraPlugins:'wysiwygarea'}; 

    CKEDITOR.inline('bg',cfg1);
    CKEDITOR.inline('exp');
    CKEDITOR.inline('ed');
    CKEDITOR.inline('skill');
    CKEDITOR.inline('other');
    CKEDITOR.inline('hobby');
</script>
```

I used above code but I can used only basic tool bar. I can't see Source (Click to see how source code of text that we input) on html element.

Comment: Do you want the full page icon or do you want the view source button or do you want both?

Comment: I want to get view source code button and I used below configure code
**`{ name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Save','Preview', 'Print' ] },`**

But it don't work for me